# Easy way of printing two numpy arrays with each element in a different line?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have a 1D numpy array `x` and another one `y = x ** 2`.
I am looking for an easier alternative to

```
for i in range(x.size):
    print(x[i], y[i])
```

With one array one can do `print(*x, sep = '\n')` which is easier than a for loop. I'm thinking of something like converting `x` and `y` to arrays of strings and then adding them up into an array `z` and then using `print(*z, sep = '\n')`. However, I tried to do that but numpy gives an error when the add operation is performed.

Edit: This is the function I use for this

```
def to_str(*args):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join([str(ls[i]) for ls in args]) for i in range(len(args[0]))]) + '\n'

>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> y = x ** 2
>>> print(to_str(x,y))
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81

>>>
```

Comment: What's difficult about that loop?  How much control do you need?  With or without brackets, commas etc.   I'd probably use `for xy in zip(x,y)`.

Comment: @hpaulj It's not that it is difficult but that I find it cumbersome for a task that should be very easy to do. For example, if I want to add a blank line after printing I have to add another line with a print() command. I find that it would be nice to have a one line (short) command to print both lists. It is easy to define a function that does this but I wanted to know if someone can tell us how to do that. I want it to print the numbers separated by white spaces so that I can use another program to plot them.

Comment: So you really want to write to a file?  Not just print to screen?  Have you looked at `np.savetxt`?

Comment: Sometimes I want it to be printed to the screen before saving to a file (to check the output); then, if I want to save it it's easy to redirect the output to a file. Otherwise I need to have the file names before running the program, and open the files if I want to check the output.

Comment: Either way, learn to  join the 2 arrays, either with list `zip` or one on the `numpy` concatenate/stack functions.

Answer (score 1):

or if something quick and dirty is enough:

```
print(np.array((x,y)).T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines -

```
# Input arrays
In [238]: x
Out[238]: array([14, 85, 79, 89, 41])

In [239]: y
Out[239]: array([13, 79, 13, 79, 11])

# Join arrays with " "
In [240]: z = [" ".join(item) for item in np.column_stack((x,y)).astype(str)]

# Finally print it
In [241]: print(*z, sep='\n')
14 13
85 79
79 13
89 79
41 11

# Original approach for printing
In [242]: for i in range(x.size):  
     ...:     print(x[i], y[i])
     ...:     
14 13
85 79
79 13
89 79
41 11
```

To make things a bit more compact, `np.column_stack((x,y))` could be replaced by `np.vstack((x,y)).T`.

There are few other methods to create `z` as listed below -

```
z = [str(i)[1:-1] for i in zip(x,y)] # Prints commas between elems
z = [str(i)[1:-1] for i in np.column_stack((x,y))]
z = [str(i)[1:-1] for i in np.vstack((x,y)).T]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way without loop:

```
print(np.array2string(np.column_stack((x, y)),separator=',').replace(' [ ','').replace('],', '').strip('[ ]'))
```

Demo:

```
In [86]: x
Out[86]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [87]: y
Out[87]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16])
In [85]: print(np.array2string(np.column_stack((x, y)),separator=',').replace(' [ ','').replace('],', '').strip('[ ]'))
0, 0
1, 1
2, 4
3, 9
4,16
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues - combining the 2 arrays, and printing the result

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(4)
In [2]: b = a**2
In [3]: ab = [a,b]     # join arrays in a simple list
In [4]: ab
Out[4]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 4, 9])]
In [6]: list(zip(*ab))     # 'transpose' that list
Out[6]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)]
```

That `zip(*)` is a useful tool or idiom.

I could use your `print(*a, sep...)` method with this

```
In [11]: print(*list(zip(*ab)), sep='\n')
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 4)
(3, 9)
```

Using `sep` is a neat `py3` trick, but is rarely used.  I'm not even sure how to do the equivalent with the older py2 print statement.

But if we convert the list of arrays into a 2d array we have more options.

```
In [12]: arr = np.array(ab)
In [13]: arr
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 4, 9]])
In [14]: np.vstack(ab)   # does the same thing
Out[14]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 4, 9]])
```

For simply looking at the 2 arrays together this `arr` is quite useful.  And if the lines get too long, transpose it:

```
In [15]: arr.T
Out[15]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 9]])
In [16]: print(arr.T)
[[0 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 4]
 [3 9]]
```

Note that array print format is different that for nested lists.  That's intentional.

The brackets seldom get in the way of understanding the display.  They even help with the array becomes 3d and higher.

For printing a file that can be read by other programs, `np.savetxt` is quite useful.  It lets me specify the delimiter, and the format for each column or line.

```
In [17]: np.savetxt('test.csv', arr.T, delimiter=',',fmt='%10d')
```

In `ipython` I can look at the file with a simple system call:

```
In [18]: cat test.csv
         0,         0
         1,         1
         2,         4
         3,         9
```

I can omit the `delimiter` parameter.

I can reload it with `loadtxt`

```
In [20]: np.loadtxt('test.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=int)
Out[20]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 9]])
```

In Py3 it is hard to write `savetxt` to the screen.  It operates on a byte string file, and `sys.stdout` is unicode.  In Py2 `np.savetxt(sys.stdout, ...)` might work.

`savetxt` is not sophisticated.  In this example, it is essentially doing a `fwrite` equivalent of:

```
In [21]: for row in arr.T:
    ...:     print('%10d,%10d'%tuple(row))
    ...:     
         0,         0
         1,         1
         2,         4
         3,         9
```